# mouseup event is not fired when you release button on another element or somewhere outside

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousedown, mouseup

I have two `div` elements. When I press mouse button on one of them, then move mouse to another one or just somewhere else and then release the button, `mouseup` event is not fired. It is actually fired, but only for the first several random times (usually 1…10). Then it stops. Mouse curser turns to a stop sign and only `mousedown` event is fired.
I tried to add `mouseup`  eventlistener to `document.documentElement` and `document` element as it was suggested here but it did not help. Mouse curser is still turning to a stop sign after several successful mouseups and does not fire until page is reloaded.
It still fires perfectly if you release the button on the same element.
How to make `mouseup` event to be fired always when mouse button is released disregarding where you have started and finished? It is crucial for my program.
I checked it in Chrome. In Firefox it works almost the same, but the number of possible `mouseup` events on another then started element is little bit more (up to 20). Then the same stop sign appears. 
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuQvB.jpg)
[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hezk06jo/3/)

**I have found Solution!!!**

[This topic was very much helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326004/prevent-selection-in-html)
So why does the browser shows stop sign when you move the mouse with pressed button? Because it thinks *you are trying to drag this element!* But why it does not protest when you do it for the first (or several first) time? Because pressing mouse first time you....just *select* this element. Then you try to drag it and only this draws a protest of the browser and it shows stop sign. **During showing stop sign browser cannot fire any mouse events.**
So how to prevent browser from thinking you are going to select and drag this element. It’s very simple. Just add `-webkit-user-select: none;` in the CSS for this element (it’s for Chrome, for Firefox the prefix will be `-moz-` and so on).
Now all mouse events will work disregarding when, why and in which order mouse buttons were pressed!
[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hezk06jo/15/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing MouseUp event if releasing not over the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831589/losing-mouseup-event-if-releasing-not-over-the-same-element)

Comment: nope, it did not help=(

Comment: seems to work for div but not for button